# XCode Importing Libaries Incorrectly

Tags: swift, xcode, import, core-graphics

In my file I have

`import Library1`

which includes

`extension CGPoint`.

However when I try to use a function defined in Library1, I get compile errors:

`Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member '-examplefunction-'`.

I know the problem is on my local environment because jenkins and my peers can build the code fine. I've restarted XCode and rebooted several times, anybody know what the issue is?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build-folder (Cmd-Shift-K)?

Comment: I actually have cleaned several times unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your particular case.
but, be sure that your extension and methods in the framework have *public* access level